# Soap damage to keys on 2012 macbook Air

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, damage, mouse-keys

I've owned a 2012 Macbook Air for >8 years and it's been the best computer I've ever owned.

Throughout the years, I've sometimes washed the keys and screen with soap and water (small amounts).

A few months ago, I washed the keys and then realized shortly after that several of them do not work. From what I've read, this is due to electrical damage with the keys' circuitry.

I've removed the keys and attempted to clean the inside with a cotton swab and rubbing alcohol. In addition to spraying it with canned air.

No dice.

Seems I might need a new keyboard. This seems to be a hard fix to do alone and I've got a quote from a trusted local shop that can do it for ~$175.

Currently, I'm using the laptop with an external keyboard. This gets pretty cumbersome and it loses its portability. If the laptop has to act as a desktop from now on, then I can live with that.

Just wondering if there's any possible quick fix I can try with the keys before considering dishing out money. Thanks!

Comment: A suggestion for when the keyboard gets fixed. To clean a keyboard: *First* canned air to blow out the dust and other stuff. *Second* spray a **very small amount** of eyeglass cleaning solution (alcohol and water) on a microfiber cloth and rub gently on the keys (with the Mac off). Note that the cloth should be just barely be moist. If you can squeeze the cloth and liquid comes out you have applied **way too much** liquid. Also it is unlikely there is a quick fix at this time as the damage has already been done.

Comment: Probably not.  You've gotten contaminants under the membrane, even if the water evaporates, the residue of the cleaner you used will still be there.

Comment: No way to somehow "erase" the soap residue?

Also, think it's worth the $175 to fix. Could be worth it if it gives me another 18months of portability. Rather than buying a new macbook right now. Thanks!